# How to calculate to second day of the next month?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

For unit testing I need the duration, how long it is until the next second day of the month.
Example:
Today => 20. Jan 2018
Next second day of month => 2. Feb 2018

What I need: Time in milliseconds until 2. Feb 2018

Comment: If the date is `1. Feb 2018` is the next day "next second day of month" going to be `2. Feb 2018`, or should it be `2. Mar 2018` ?

Comment: 2. Feb 2018. I have a cron job that runs on every second day of the month. For testing I have to maike sure it works correct

Comment: Ok, what if the date is `2. Feb 2018`, should it calculate the time until the current date, or the next date `2. Mar 2018` ?

Comment: 2. Mar 2018 would be perfect but if the cronjob also triggers at 2. Feb is is not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem using moment.js with the flowing process.

1. First find the second month.

`let nextMonth = moment(new Date()).add(1, "M").toDate(); ==> Wed Oct 02 2019 18:24:31 GMT+0600`

2. Find start of the month.

`let startOfMonth = moment(nextMonth).startOf("month").toDate(); ==> Tue Oct 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0600`

3. Find the second day of the month.

`let secondDay = moment(startOfMonth).add(1, "d").toDate(); ==> Wed Oct 02 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0600`

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the time difference until the end of the month and then add an additional 2 days worth of milliseconds to the end of your calculated time (`2*((60000*60)*24)`). I've provided a generalized approach which allows you to perform this calculation for the `nth` day in a given month:

```js
const get_next_nth = n => today =>
  today.getDate() < n-1 ? 
    (n-(today.getDate()+1))*60000*60*24 : 
    (new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0) - today) + n*((60000*60)*24);
  
const get_next_second = get_next_nth(2);
const res = get_next_second(new Date());
console.log(res); // m/s until next 2nd date
console.log(new Date(new Date().getTime() + res).toDateString()); // string version of next 2nd date
```